# ActionScript 3.0 linebreaks in textfields

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, text, line-breaks

Can a TextField can contain different kinds of linebreaks?

I save and load text from an input field into an XML. I save it as CDATA tags including linebreaks.

This is what happens:

1. I type a text with linebreaks into the textfield
2. I save the text to the XML
3. I empty the textfield
4. I load the xml into the textfield - everything looks as expected, linebreaks are present
5. I save the exact same textfield again (the only difference this time the content was loaded and not handtyped)
6. This time the XML does not contain any linebreaks
7. when I load it again, the text doesn't have linebreaks

How can this be?

//here is an example that demonstrates the issue:

```
var xml1 = <xml>
               <elm/>
           </xml>;

xml1.elm.text = new XML("<![CDATA[" + textField.text + "]]>");

trace(xml1);

textField.text="";
textField.appendText(xml1.elm.text());

var xml2 = <xml>
               <elm/>
           </xml>;

xml2.elm.text = new XML("<![CDATA[" + textField.text + "]]>");

trace(xml2);
```

I enter into a textField the text

this is
a linebreak

And run the code on it. Although the textfield looks still fine afterwards (displays the linebreak) the output of the code shows:

```
<xml>
  <elm><![CDATA[this is
a linebreak]]></elm>
</xml>
<xml>
  <elm><![CDATA[this isa linebreak]]></elm>
</xml>
```

How can that be?

Comment: Is your textfield with the multiline property enabled? What does trace(textField.htmlText) show?

Comment: Your example is too convoluted, you need to break it into smaller parts. For example, what do you get if you simply trace(textField.text)? What if you use toXMLString() instead of relying on the automatic string conversion, etc.

Comment: @felipermaia: `.multiline = true;` is for user input and so would be totally irrelevant in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding your text value

```
xml1.elm.text = new XML("<![CDATA[" + encodeURIComponent(textField.text) + "]]>");
```